# Looking for great examples of MVC frameworks

Tags: model-view-controller, user-interface, language-agnostic

I've recently heavily gotten into Javascript programming. Currently I'm building a 'Fat client' powered by a PHP-based REST webservice.

This is going pretty well, but I want to learn more.. become an expert if you will.

My background is mostly MVC in PHP, so building true real-time GUI applications based on the MVC model is pretty new. MVC exists in PHP, but it's quite different. In javascript, because it's 'live' there's a much stronger emphasis for message-passing and events.

I'm learning based on the YUI3 and Backbone.js frameworks. I believe this is a solid foundation. I do feel though that, in order to become better I should try to learn from other (non-javascript) MVC systems.

I have some (very distant) memories of playing around with both Visual Basic and Delphi (6 and 7). Even though I'm sure these have solid frameworks behind them, there must be other frameworks out there that are great to learn from. I'd love to see a solid, non-javascript, lightweight framework or language I can learn from and borrow concepts from.

So my real question is: in the great history of GUI programming, what are some good examples of articles, books, or codebases I can read to strengthen my understanding of MVC, what has worked in the past and what has not, and how to create an elegant but powerful design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chapter 11 of [Beautiful Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059651798X) is about the MVC architecture in Emacs.  Even if Emacs is not your cup of tea, it's still an interesting case study. An application that has been in active use and development for 24 years must be doing something right.

Comment: Yes: this is exactly the type of stuff I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

It cost a bit of money but the DoFactory stuff is great, I used it. Show how to implement enterprise level applications with MVC and a few other frameworks.

http://www.dofactory.com/products/products.aspx